# How to use full width table in LaTeX?

Tags: tables, two-column

i am trying to use full width table in LaTeX.

my latex code looks like this:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
%\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{cite}
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
  \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
  % \graphicspath{{../pdf/}{../jpeg/}}
  % \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png}
\else
  \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
  % \graphicspath{{../eps/}}
  % \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
\fi
%\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
% \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{listings}
%\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
%  \usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
%\else
%  \usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
%\fi
%\usepackage{fixltx2e}
%\usepackage{stfloats}
% \usepackage{dblfloatfix}
%\ifCLASSOPTIONcaptionsoff
%  \usepackage[nomarkers]{endfloat}
% \let\MYoriglatexcaption\caption
% \renewcommand{\caption}[2][\relax]{\MYoriglatexcaption[#2]{#2}}
%\fi
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}



\begin{document}
\title{network design}
\author{Loren dorem}
\markboth{nreis, May~2016}%
{Shell \MakeLowercase{\textit{et al.}}: Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for Computer Society Journals}
\date{\normalsize\today}

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}| }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{F1-accuracy} \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Methods}& \textbf{first dataset} &\textbf{second dataset} &\textbf{third dataset} & \textbf{forth dataset}\\
 \hline
 first   & 0.878    &0.648&   0.858 & 0.486\\
 second   & 0.879  & 0.654   &0.857 & 0.480\\
third & 0.863&  0.664 & 0.855 & - \\
forth & 0.855    &0.664 & 0.856&  -\\
fifth &0.858   & 0.691  & 0.868&0.528\\
\hline
 \textbf{sixth}& \textbf{0.899} &\textbf{0.686} &\textbf{0.873} & \textbf{0.565}\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\begin{figure}[!h]
 \begin{center}
 \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{final.png}
 \caption{F1-accuracy of reuters and slashdot dataset}
 \label{fig:FeatLearn}
 \end{center}
 \end{figure}

 \begin{figure}[!h]
 \begin{center}
 \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{final_rc3.png}
 \caption{F1-accuracy of rcv1 and aapd dataset}
 \label{fig:FeatLearn}
 \end{center}
 \end{figure}

For POS data set, we achieved state of the art tagging accuracy with or without the use of extra data
resource. POS data set has been extensively tested
and the past improvement can be realized in Table
4. Our test accuracy is 97.55 which is significantly better than others in the confidence level of
95. In addition, our BI-LSTM-CRF model already reaches a good accuracy without the use of
the Senna embedding

All chunking systems performance is shown in
table 5. Kudo et al. won the CoNLL 2000 challenge with a F1 score of 93.48 Their approach
was a SVM based classifier. They later improved
the results up to 93.91. Recent work include the
CRF based models (Sha and Pereira, 2003; Mcdonald et al., 2005; Sun et al., 2008). More recent is (Shen and Sarkar, 2005) which obtained
95.23 accuracy with a voting classifier scheme,
where each classifier is trained on different tag
representations (IOB, IOE, etc.). Our model outperforms all reported systems except (Shen and
Sarkar, 2005).
The performance of all systems for NER is
shown in table 6. (Florian et al., 2003) presented the best system at the NER CoNLL 2003
challenge, with 88.76 F1 score. They used a
combination of various machine-learning classifiers. The second best performer of CoNLL 2003
(Chieu., 2003) was 88.31 F1, also with the help
of an external gazetteer. Later, (Ando and Zhang.,
2005) reached 89.31 F1 with a semi-supervised
approach. The best F1 score of 90.90 was reported in (Passos et al., 2014) which employed a

\end{document}
```

But when i am adding two images, images are overlapping the table like this:

[image]

How to fix that?

Thank you !

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) you are much much mire likely to get help if you provide a full (but minimal example) that others can copy and test as is instead of having been given a sniplet like this (that does not match the image)

Comment: @daleif updated the code

Comment: @CarLaTeX tried but not working, I've updated the code please check.

Comment: For a full-width figure you'd need a `figure*` environment, as @CarLaTeX explains. For a full-width table you'd need to add `\begin{table*}...\end{table*}` around your `\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}`.

Comment: @LianTzeLim I tried but then table is appearing bottom of the paper.
https://www.overleaf.com/8679125826vkfwgtrdnsyk

Comment: And there is gap before the table, How to reduce that gap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code are several issues, for example

1. You can simply use `\usepackage graphicx` instead yours

   ```
   \ifCLASSINFOpdf
     \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
     % \graphicspath{{../pdf/}{../jpeg/}}
     % \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png}
   \else
     \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
     % \graphicspath{{../eps/}}
     % \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
   \fi
   ```

   because that package is able to evaluate the needed driver `pdftex` or `dvips` by its own.
2. You used a lot of packages not needed for the issue here. I deleted them in the following mwe.
3. In an two column layout you have to use environment `table*` to get an table spanning both columns. See the following mwe.
4. Use inside `figure` command `\centering` instead environment `center` (less white space around the figure).
5. Do not write "table 6" in your text, use command `\ref` instead like `table~\ref{tab:methods}`. See that I added an caption to your table with an following label I used here.
6. Use `\cite{}` etc. to add your cited bib entries into your text, do not write them manually, that will only produce errors in the text ...

The corrected MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx} % <===============================================
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

\title{network design}
\author{Loren dorem}
\markboth{nreis, May~2016}%
{Shell \MakeLowercase{\textit{et al.}}: Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for Computer Society Journals}
\date{\normalsize\today}

\maketitle % <==========================================================
\begin{table*} % <======================================================
  \caption{table caption}\label{tab:methods} % <========================
\begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}| }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{F1-accuracy} \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Methods}& \textbf{first dataset} &\textbf{second dataset} &\textbf{third dataset} & \textbf{forth dataset}\\
 \hline
 first   & 0.878    &0.648&   0.858 & 0.486\\
 second   & 0.879  & 0.654   &0.857 & 0.480\\
third & 0.863&  0.664 & 0.855 & - \\
forth & 0.855    &0.664 & 0.856&  -\\
fifth &0.858   & 0.691  & 0.868&0.528\\
\hline
 \textbf{sixth}& \textbf{0.899} &\textbf{0.686} &\textbf{0.873} & \textbf{0.565}\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering % <========================================================
  \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image-a} % final.png
  \caption{F1-accuracy of reuters and slashdot dataset}
  \label{fig:FeatLearn}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering % <========================================================
  \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image-a} % final_rc3.png
  \caption{F1-accuracy of rcv1 and aapd dataset}
  \label{fig:FeatLearn}
\end{figure}

For POS data set, we achieved state of the art tagging accuracy with or without the use of extra data
resource. POS data set has been extensively tested
and the past improvement can be realized in Table
4. Our test accuracy is 97.55 which is significantly better than others in the confidence level of
95. In addition, our BI-LSTM-CRF model already reaches a good accuracy without the use of
the Senna embedding

All chunking systems performance is shown in
table 5. Kudo et al. won the CoNLL 2000 challenge with a F1 score of 93.48 Their approach
was a SVM based classifier. They later improved
the results up to 93.91. Recent work include the
CRF based models (Sha and Pereira, 2003; Mcdonald et al., 2005; Sun et al., 2008). More recent is (Shen and Sarkar, 2005) which obtained
95.23 accuracy with a voting classifier scheme,
where each classifier is trained on different tag
representations (IOB, IOE, etc.). Our model outperforms all reported systems except (Shen and
Sarkar, 2005).
The performance of all systems for NER is
shown in table~\ref{tab:methods}. (Florian et al., 2003) presented the best system at the NER CoNLL 2003
challenge, with 88.76 F1 score. They used a
combination of various machine-learning classifiers. The second best performer of CoNLL 2003
(Chieu., 2003) was 88.31 F1, also with the help
of an external gazetteer. Later, (Ando and Zhang.,
2005) reached 89.31 F1 with a semi-supervised
approach. The best F1 score of 90.90 was reported in (Passos et al., 2014) which employed a

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Please see that the table has moved to page two, because then it is easy to start a one column part! That is the ususal behaviour of that template. If you do not want that you need to make your table shorter, for example by splitting the header into two lines to fit into one column ...

Answer (score 2):

I would write column headers in two lines. In such a case, your table can be fit in one column:

[image]

In above table I use `tabularx` for table environment, `booktabs` for rules in table  and `siunitx` for columns with numbers (which are now aligned at decimal points).

```
\documentclass[12pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs,
            tabularx}
\newcommand\mcbf[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\bfseries}X}{#1}}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newrobustcmd{\B}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont} % non-extended bold font

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{table}[htb]
\sisetup{table-format=1.3,
         detect-weight}

    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l *{4}{S} @{}}
    \toprule
 \multicolumn{5}{c}{F1-accuracy} \\
    \midrule
\mcbf{Methods}
            &   \mcbf{first dataset}
                        &   \mcbf{second dataset}
                                    &   \mcbf{third dataset}
                                                &   \mcbf{forth dataset}\\
    \midrule
 first      & 0.878     & 0.648     & 0.858     & 0.486     \\
 second     & 0.879     & 0.654     & 0.857     & 0.480     \\
third       & 0.863     & 0.664     & 0.855     & {--}      \\
forth       & 0.855     & 0.664     & 0.856     & {--}      \\
fifth       & 0.858     & 0.691     & 0.868     & 0.528     \\
    \midrule
\textbf{sixth}
            & \B 0.89   & \B 0.686  & \B 0.873  & \B 0.565  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}\lipsum[2]
    \begin{figure}[htb]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{final.png}
\caption{F1-accuracy of reuters and slashdot dataset}
\label{fig:FeatLearn}
    \end{figure}
 \lipsum[3]
    \begin{figure}[htb]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{final_rc3.png}
\caption{F1-accuracy of rcv1 and aapd dataset}
\label{fig:FeatLearn}
    \end{figure}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
With above table you will not have problems with overlapping images over table (with compiling above MWE (minimal Working Example) you can confirm thhis). Also table now has more professional look.